# Regular Expression to match special char + number

Tags: regex, syntax, pattern-matching

I have a text file with a bunch of data that I need to replace with commas.

The text I need to change is

```
/* 1 */
...
all the way till
...
/* 234 */
```

I tried using regular expression as

`/\/* [0-9] /\/`* but that does not work

Can anyone tell me the regex to select the pattern above?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\/\* \d+ \*\/
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/wU7sQ0/13

Comment: I tried, but it asked me to wait for 8 minutes. I will do that in a while :)